# Is there a sql'like "where" argument in data.table to join?

Tags: r, data.table, sqldf

let's say i have these data.tables:

```
dt1<- data.table(c("A","B","C"),c("G","H","I"),c(4,5,6)) 
dt2<- data.table(c("A","B","C"),c("D","E","F"),c(3,4,5))
```

i would like to do

```
select dt1.*,dt2.V2 from dt1 left join dt2 on 
             dt1.V1 = dt2.V1 and dt2.V3= dt1.V3 - 1
```

but with data.table. Is there a way to do it ?

In other words i would like to do a left join in data.table with a condition which here is that dt1$V1 = dt2$V1 and dt2$V3 -1 = dt1$V3 .

Comment: Yes sorry i'll edit

Comment: Mmh... maybe this `merge(dt1[,.(V1,V2,V3=V3-1)],dt2,by.x=c('V1','V3'),by.y=c('V1','V3'),all=TRUE)` ?

Comment: or `dt1[dt2, on = 'V1'][V3 -1 == i.V3][,i.V3 := NULL][]`.

Comment: if you want a `sql`-oriented query , look into `sqldf` package [here](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf)

Comment: I'm already using sqldf but it's too slow. data.table is faster and i'm working on huge data.frames without a distributed architecture

Comment: can i add more condition in the on ? mt1022 ?

Comment: Sure you can add more exact joins or non-equi joins in `on`.

Comment: nice i just tried it works and can i directly change the column name of the new column added by the join ?

Comment: And i have another and last question, if the both data frame have not the same columns name, how can i deal with it if i want as condition dt1.V1 = dt2. V4

Comment: when i try in my original data.table i got this error `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 9880547 rows; more than 9141960 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again.`

Comment: You can change col names after and for dt1.V1 = dt2.V4, you can try `on = c("V1" = "V4")`

Comment: @mt1022 I think the `v3sub1 := V3-1` and then use that in an equi-join might be more idiomatic. Anyway, you might as well post an answer.

Comment: @Frank, thanks. I also thought about that initially but I want to avoid modifying original `dt1`. So I decided not to use `:=` as the first step. I didn't make an answer because I have no experience in SQL and don't know how  exactly the SQL output looks like. :(